# Is there any Islamic reason to prevent women from voting?

Tags: sharia, women, politics

While women are welcomed to vote in many Islamic countries, it seems some Islamic countries still do not let women to vote.

I believe allowing women to participate in making decision about their future is essential according to the Islamic justice.

What is the reason behind countries preventing women to vote? Is there any Islamic reason to prevent women to vote, or is it just a cultural/political issue?*

Comment: Which countries? I just know Saudi Arabia.

Comment: I did not mention any specific country to keep the question general.

Comment: It should be cultural, I guess.

Comment: A better form of the question would be... why in Islam **should** women be allowed to partake in government?

Comment: @Hanif, why in Islam women should not be allowed to partake in government? will be better

Comment: @Hanif Your title contains an answer implicitly, while I am asking if it is allowed or not.

Comment: @alekhine I think that's another question you may ask. I just focus on voting here

Comment: @Ali, I appreciate you really great question which unfortunately it is ... nowadays still ... Good luck mate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no Islamic rule that prevents Muslim women from voting.
But some eastern cultures are trying to impose their cultural limitations and cover them with fake religious causes to force people to accept those limitations.

Comment: Those who ban women voting must have some logic.

Comment: What is the logic of preventing some humans and allowing others?

Comment: @Drycola here we only accept answers that have citations.  Please provide your citations.

Comment: @Drycola in your book, it might be non Islamic but *they* might have some logic to ban women voting. Unless you provide strong evidence that you are correct.

Comment: There is no evidence that islam in its rules bans women from voting, if you have such evidence, cite it.

Comment: @Drycola You may complete your answers by providing some Ayah or Hadith about similar rights for men and women.

Comment: At least you can back your answer with some logic, e.g. something like to say as long as there is no reason to forbid something it will be considered permitted, and there is nothing in Qur'aan and Hadeeth that forbid such things. Even though I will still encourage you to consider finding some witnesses why it is allowed! Godspeed.

Comment: The issue of whether or not this answer needs citations/evidence would be better discussed in this meta post: [The "useless negative" problem](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/355/the-useless-negative-problem)